# Can I reference controls in one section from another within an Orbeon library module?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I'm trying to use the answer from [question 7590420](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590420/orbeon-form-builder-referring-to-a-control-within-a-section-template), about controlling the visibility 
by referencing a control in one section from another section, using an Orbeon library. The library contains both sections. I know I can't use `$foo = ...` but I was hoping to use a reference such as `/library/section-1/foo = ...`, as implied in the answer.

I'm not sure if its the age of the software (V4.10.2) or if I can't use library sections in this way but it seems the XPath expression is ignored. The form loads without error.

Comment: Mike, I imagine you'd like to access the value of a field from a section template. Is this correct? From where do you want to do that? -Alex

Comment: Thanks Alex, that's exactly right. The field holding the value is in a section template of an Orbeon library "form". I'm trying to get to that value from another section template in the same library. As all the sections and controls in a library must have unique names, my thinking is I should be able to use a similar syntax to that in the question. I'm just wondering if the the rules for a library differ from a form in some way I've missed - or if I'm using too old a version.

Comment: Got it Mike. I've posted a tentative answer below. This might not be what you're hoping for, but I hope this still answers your question! -Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Orbeon Forms 2016.3, you cannot access, from inside a section template, anything outside the current section template, be it other values of fields in the form using the section template, or values of fields in other section templates used by the form, even if they are defined in the same library. This might be possible in the future, when [RFE 3008](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/3008), or similar is implemented.